# How to initialize a class member using a classmethod

Tags: python, oop, class-method

I have a class, which holds some member `x` (say, some data that is needed by all instances, but independent of them):

```
class Foo(object):
    x = 23

    # some more code goes here
```

Now, the procedure of determining `x` became more complex plus I wanted to be able to "refresh" `x` at certain times, so I decided to write an extra function for it

```
class Foo(object):
    @classmethod
    def generate_x(cls):
        cls.x = 23

    # some more code goes here
```

However, this class definition lacks an initialization call of `generate_x`.

What I tried so far:

This does not work:

```
class Foo(object):

    # generate_x()     # NameError: name 'generate_x' is not defined
    # Foo.generate_x() # NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined

    @classmethod
    def generate_x(cls):
        cls.x = 23
```

This works but less clear, because code is used outside the class definition

```
class Foo(object):

    @classmethod
    def generate_x(cls):
        cls.x = 23

    # ...
Foo.generate_x()
```

Are there better alternatives to this? Is using `@classmethod` the best approach here? What I'm searching is a class-equivalent of `__init__`.

Considering code clarity, is there a better way than the latter to instantiate `Foo.x` automatically using a function?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve that isn't solved by `Foo.x = 42`?

Comment: As I said, the construction of `x` is more complicated, `Foo.x=23` is just an illustration. I want to (i) instantiate `Foo.x` automatically using a *function* and I want it to happen automatically.

Comment: If you are looking for the class-equivalent of `__init__` then take a look at this article about metaprogramming in Python: https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/ and do some experimenting with `__new__` and `__prepare__`.

Comment: @NPE This is so far my best answer, but as I write, I would prefer an alternative where the code is inside the class definition for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by using a decorator:

```
def with_x(cls):
   cls.generate_x()
   return cls

@with_x
class Foo(object):
   @classmethod
   def generate_x(cls):
      cls.x = 23
```

(That said, I personally would just call `Foo.generate_x` explicitly after the class declaration, and avoid all the magic altogether.)

Comment: Thanks, I will stick to `Foo.generate_x()`, having asked *if* there is a more elegant way, "No" is also a perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a descriptor.

```
class Complicated:
    def __init__(self, location, get_value):
        self.location =location 
        self.get_value = staticmethod(get_value)
    def __get__(self, obj, owner):
        try:
            a = getattr(owner, self.location)
        except AttributeError:
            a = self.get_value()
            setattr(owner, self.location, a)
        return a

class My class:
     x = Complicated ('_x', get_x)
```